# How does OpenSea work with all the functions?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, nft, opensea

I know it has smart contracts at the backend but how does it store the profile picture for an address ?  and also likes and dislikes and auction and all other functionalities.
Can somebody please explain this I have searched a lot and can not find a in depth explanation for the architecture ?

Answer (score 0):

> *how does it store the profile picture for an address ? and also likes and dislikes and auction and all other functionalities.*

These are platform specific data for OpenSea, not part of the collection contract. Meaning they are not stored onchain.

So without knowing source codes of the OpenSea platform, we can only guess the exact location where the data is stored, but my educated guess is a relational DB (e.g. PostgreSQL, MariaDB, ...).